# How to create and fetch relational records in core data

Tags: core-data, relationship, fetch

Total newbie question now... Suffice to say, I have searched for a completely noddy explanation but have not found anything 'dumb' enough. The problem is...

I have created a core data stack in which I have a entity called 'Client' and an entity called 'Car'. It is a one-to-many relationship.

So far i have successfully created and fetched the client list using code from apple's tutorial. Once I select a client, I then push a new tableViewController which should list the Cars for that chosen client.

First question...

I am used to sql style database programming where if I wanted to add a car to a client, I would simply add a 'ClientID' tag to the 'Car' record thereby providing the relationship to a specific client. How do I do the equivalent in core data? My understanding from my reading is adding attributes to point to other entities isnt necessary - core data maintains this relationship for you without needing additional attributes in the entities.

Second question...

As and when I have created a 'car' entity and successfully linked it to a 'Client'. How to I create a fetch which will retrieve just THAT client's cars. I could alter the code from apple to fetch ALL cars but I don't know how to fetch cars associated with a given client.  From my reading, I think I need to use predicates, but apples predicate documentation stands alone and does not give clear guidance on how to use it with core data

I realise how noddy this is, but I cant find an idiots guide anywhere...

Any help/code exmaples much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have answered my own question. For those who have found my question and would like to know the answer, it is extremely simple...

Firstly, to create a 'Car' and associate it with a 'Client'. Firstly create a 'Car' as you normally would and simply add this line of code...

```
newCar.client = client;
```

This sets the 'client' relationship on the 'Car' record to the client in question.

Secondly, I had thought that if you had a client and needed to find their cars, you would need a new fetch. But not so! Simply use the following lines of code...

```
NSSet *cars = client.cars;
[self setCarsArray:[cars allObjects]];
```

The first line uses "client.cars" o follow the object graph to determine the cars this client has and populates them in an NSSet. The second line then populates a NSArray which is declared in the current viewcontroller which can be used to for display purposes.

Sorted!!